# Ansible: Loop over template with related variables

Tags: ansible, template, variables

Given the **variable** structure

```yaml
syncjobs:
  - filename: output1.bash
    content: data1
  - filename: output2.bash
    content: data2
```

I want to loop over it creating the files with **ansible.builtin.template** using the field **filename** for the **dest**.
I can achieve this with

```yaml
- name: Create scripts
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: template.bash.j2
    dest: /opt/bin/{{ item.filename }}
    owner: root
    mode: "u+x,o-r"
    backup: true
  with_items: "{{ syncjobs }}"
```

however I can't figure out how to address the specific **content** field from the **syncjobs** dict in the template file.
Of course I can access the variable **syncjobs**, but I need to address the **content** field from the related **dictionary** for every specific iteration.

I tried to set an additional fact like **current_filename** to **item.filename** inside an **ansible.builtin.block**, but unfortunately loops does not seem to be supported for blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly the same way as in the playbook. There is the same `{{ item }}` variable in the template, so you can refer to `{{ item.content }}` in the template file. (Actually, *all* the playbook variables are available in the template, just the same set that exist at that specific place of the playbook where the `ansible.builtin.template` was called.)

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thank you very much!
This is kind of so obvious that for some reason I just didn't think of ;-)